# ¿Que se debe saber para usar backtracking y divide y venceras?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Realmente estos dos conceptos son importantes en la programación, realmente llevo poco tiempo en la programación.

Se que los dos temas pueden ser extensos de contestar, pero **a lo que quiero llegar** es que para poder implementar algunos de estos dos conceptos a un algoritmo me imagino que se debe conocer algunos patrones que me indiquen como coger el problema y aplicar esos conceptos.

> Debe haber algo que se debe saber a nivel general que me permita identificar como implementar estos conceptos al problema y lograr solucionarlo.

**Lo que quiero sabes es como debo abordar el problema para implementar el backtracking y asi resolverlo; del mismo modo a divide y vencerás.**

Comment: Lastimosamente, así no funciona el sitio. Necesitas proveer un problema que tienes mientras diseñas este tipo de algoritmos (que no están asociados a programación funcional ni a ningún paradigma de programación en particular) y nosotros te ayudaremos a resolver ese problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Modificada

Comment: No veo que muestres un problema mientras diseñas algún algoritmo de este tipo. Te recomiendo que revises uno a uno. Por ejemplo, para backtracking puedes programar el problema de las 8 reinas o las torres de hanoi, para divide y vencerás puedes implementar el cálculo de potencia de números y casos de fork-join.

Comment: [Backtracking](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuelta_atr%C3%A1s) y [Divide y vencerás](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_divide_y_vencer%C3%A1s)